# Toggle hidden fields in Podio via .NET API

Tags: c#, .net, api, podio

We are trying to hide fields in podio via the api using the application service UpdateAnAppField method. We are able to use this call by passing in appID, fieldID, and a FieldConfig object. We were able to change the label of a field in podio, verifying the call works in at least one way, however we are unable to change the visibility of the field using this call. We have tried the following things with no luck:

1.)

```
FieldConfig config = new FieldConfig { Label = "blah", Hidden = true, Visible = false };
await podio.ApplicationService.UpdateAnAppField(appId, fieldId, config);
```

2.)

```
FieldConfig config = new FieldConfig { Label = "blah", Hidden = true};
await podio.ApplicationService.UpdateAnAppField(appId, fieldId, config);
```

3.)

```
FieldConfig config = new FieldConfig { Label = "blah", Visible = false };
await podio.ApplicationService.UpdateAnAppField(appId, fieldId, config);
```

The label does indeed change any time we want it to, but the visibility is not affected by any of these calls.

Is there a different way to do this so we may manipulate the visibility of existing fields in apps?

*We are using Podio.Async*

(I have read the documentation)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Always Hidden" feature is not exposed in that SDK apparently. There is a field called "hidden_create_view_edit" which maps to that property of a field. You can access it using dynamic properties.